url_private_download without xoxe token
we scrape the messenger service Slack for a project. This requires to download the images that are available in messages. This is done with the link which can be found in url_private_download. In the Slack documentation and confirmed by support, a xoxe token should actually be directly linked to the link. This would look like this: ‘url_private_download’: ‘https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T019B299WNQ-F05UA7XQXHS/download/canvas?t=xoxe-1317077336772-EXAMPLE-TOKEN-INFO’
Unfortunately, I can't find the xoxe token and with other tokens such as xoxc or xoxd I only get errors with a GET request in Python.
Where can I find the xoxe token?
And are there alternatives to download the image?
Many thanks in advance.
